# Remove first element from array and implement conditional subtraction from all subsequent values in the array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, subtraction

I am trying to design a function to perform subtraction while iterating over the numbers in an array.
The first number needs to be removed and used for subtraction with the remaining numbers. Upon performing subtraction, no value should be reduced to a negative number. Additionally, if a new value is encountered which is greater than the value being preserved, the preserved value will be increased to the amount of the greater value.

My current code:

```
function pairwiseDifference($array) 
{
    $n = count($array) - 1;  // you can add the -1 here
    $diff = 0;
    $result = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
        // absolute difference between 
        // consecutive numbers 
        $diff = abs($array[$i] - $arry[$i + 1]); 
        echo $diff." ";
        array_push($result, $diff);   // use array_push() to add new items to an array
    }

    return $result;  // return the result array
}

$array = [20,10,10,50];

// Percent of commisions are: 
pairwiseDifference($array);
```

My code incorrectly prints `10,0,40`, and I need the following values as output: `0,0,30`.

Some additional inputs and desired outputs:

```
$input = [20, 10, 10, 50, 100, 25];
$output = [    0,  0, 30,  50,  0];
```

---

```
$input = [80, 20, 30, 10, 50];
$output = [    0,  0,  0,  0];
```

---

```
$input = [10, 40, 10, 50, 40];
$output = [   30,  0, 10,  0];
```

Comment: What should be the output for `array(20,10,10,50,100,25);`  ?

Comment: Hi @nice_dev consider the first number will be everytime my commision in this case (20) so the otuput will be (0,0,30,50,0), you have to understand that the higer number are the max commision, but depend of where are. For example if i have array(80,20,30,10,50) my output are 0,0,0,0 becouse my commision (80) are higher than the others, so dont need compensation. If i have this array(10,40,10,50,40) the output will be 30,0,10,0 becouse i take 10 and the rest are total commision to arrive at max commision (50) (10my+30+10 = 50)

Comment: So there is a running maximum when taking commission, understood.

Comment: @nice_dev yes Nice, are called Stair Step Break away plan in mlm system [link](https://www.epixelmlmsoftware.com/stair-step-break-away-compensation-plan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your first element of the array is your commission and the others are the the commissions of parents, and since it seems that you don't want to include your commission in the result array, you can do something like this:

```
function pairwiseDifference($arry) 
{
    $n = count($arry);
    $diff = 0;
    $result = array();

    $myComm = $arry[0];  // your commision

    for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) 
    {
        $diff = 0;                     // set $diff to 0 as default
        if($myComm < $arry[$i])          // if your commision < parent commision
            $diff = $arry[$i] - $myComm;
        echo $diff." ";
        array_push($result, $diff);
    }

    return $result;
}

$arry = array(20,10,10,50);
echo "<br> Percent of commisions are: ";

$diffArray = pairwiseDifference($arry);

echo $diffArray[0];  // prints 0
echo $diffArray[1];  // prints 0
echo $diffArray[2];  // prinst 30
```

Comment: Sorry @Ivan86 but your code otuput -10 -0 -40 i dont know why

Comment: @GINOGINI I was missing a few `$` symbols. Should now work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To tweak the logic according to your code, there would be only 3 modifications.

- Create a `$max` variable and assign it the value of `$arry[0]`.
- Make difference as `0` if current max is greater than current one, else take the difference.
- Calculate the new max again using `max()` function.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function pairwiseDifference($arry) 
{
    $n = count($arry) - 1;  // you can add the -1 here
    $diff = 0;
    $result = array();
    $max = $arry[0]; // new addition
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)  // new modification <= n instead of < n
   { 
       // absolute difference between 
       // consecutive numbers 
       $diff = $max < $arry[$i] ? $arry[$i] - $max : 0; // new modification
       $max = max($max, $arry[$i]); // new modification
       echo $diff." ";
       array_push($result, $diff);   // use array_push() to add new items to an array
   }

   return $result;  // return the result array
}

$arry = array(20,10,10,50);
echo "<br> Percent of commisions are: ";

// this echos 10,0,40 and assigns whatever your function returns 
// to the variable $diffArray
$diffArray = pairwiseDifference($arry);
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the step of shifting the first value off of the input array, unpack the array when passing it into the custom function.

In the function signature, isolate the first value as a variable, then collect all remaining values as an array.

Loop over the shortened array, if the current value is greater than the amount to be subtracted, set the current value to the difference between the two and update the amount to "subtract by" to the original value.  Otherwise reduce the current value to zero.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tMUe5h))

```
function reduceCommissions(int $subtractBy, int ...$commissions): array
{
    return array_map(
        function($v) use (&$subtractBy) {
            if ($v > $subtractBy) {
                $difference = $v - $subtractBy;
                $subtractBy = $v;
            }
            return $difference ?? 0;
        },
        $commissions
    );
}

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export(reduceCommissions(...$test));
}
```

Tests and output:

```
$tests = [
    [20,10,10,50],        // [0, 0, 30]
    [20,10,10,50,100,25], // [0, 0, 30, 50, 0]
    [10,40,10,50,40]      // [30, 0, 10, 0];
];
```